# With just one thread group and one CSV file, several users should be able to process the orders

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

200 distinct users will login independently and complete the transactions; one user will log in once, execute three orders simultaneously, and then log out.

So I need to set up a single thread group with a single CSV file to handle 200 individual users, each of whom should execute three jobs.

To pass the values, I used baolu-csv-data-file-config, and it worked.

And I used a stepping thread group, which is functioning, to add 200 users to a single thread group.

I now need to incorporate both into a single script.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 200 users to execute actions and then shut down consider using "normal" [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) because Stepping Thread Group assumes letting user to run some time after it's started so it might be the case the user will execute the transaction more than once.

So configure it as follows:

1. Number of threads: 200
2. Loop Count: 1
3. [Ramp-up period](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period): according to your test scenario and the load you're trying to achieve. If you don't have better idea you can stick to [JMeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group):

   > The ramp-up period tells JMeter how long to take to "ramp-up" to the full number of threads chosen. If 10 threads are used, and the ramp-up period is 100 seconds, then JMeter will take 100 seconds to get all 10 threads up and running. Each thread will start 10 (100/10) seconds after the previous thread was begun. If there are 30 threads and a ramp-up period of 120 seconds, then each successive thread will be delayed by 4 seconds.
   >
   > Ramp-up needs to be long enough to avoid too large a work-load at the start of a test, and short enough that the last threads start running before the first ones finish (unless one wants that to happen).
   >
   > Start with Ramp-up = number of threads and adjust up or down as needed.